# Is it possible to select multiple directories at once with JFileChooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser, directory

As the title states, is there a way to select multiple directories at once (all sub-directories immediately within a primary directory) with JFileChooser so I don't have to re-open the file chooser window for each directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again I've solved my own question after asking it.

The thing that was preventing me from getting it to work previously was I was using the check for multi-select rather than the set for multi-select, and apparently was using that wrong as well as I kept getting an error.  Anyway, the working version is below:

```
class AddDirectory implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        File[] theDir = null;
        theDir = selectDir();
        if(theDir != null) {
            for(File z : theDir) {
                String[] curRow = { z.toString(), "Waiting"};
                dlm.addRow(curRow);
            }
        }
        return;
    }   
    private File[] selectDir() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(lastDir);
        fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int showOpenDialog = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (showOpenDialog != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            return null;
        }
        File[] uploadDir = fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
        lastDir = new File(uploadDir[uploadDir.length-1].getParent());
        return uploadDir;
    }
}
```

Once I get the directories, they're loaded into a JTable to be modified before running the rest of my code on them.